# ACTION_SCREEN_ON makes screen on or just tells about this action?

Tags: android, android-intent, screen

does sending

```
private static final String Screenon = Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON;
sendBroadcastMessage(Screenon);
```

turns screen on? with the help of this intent we can only find out, if the screen is going to be turned on, am i right?

i need ti know it just decide whether the given util class given to us works fine (this class must turn screen on/off and it tries to do so via these intents)

Answer (score 0):

yes, this BroadcastMessage should turn the screen on. If it doesnt do that, look into
the AndroidManifest.xml - the app needs permissions to do that.